# Force download iOS 5.0.1 symbols

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, symbolicate

A customer sent me a crash log from an iOS 5.0.1 (9A405) device. I'm running Xcode 4.2 on Snow Leopard. The system parts of the crash log call stack fail to symbolicate, and it seems that they're relevant to the crash; there are no iOS 5.0.1 symbols in Xcode. I don't have a 5.0.1 device, and I don't think I can install it, now that 5.1 is the latest.

Is there a way for force-download symbols for a given iOS version in Xcode without plugging in a device?

EDIT: seems like you can force a specific iOS version to a device using Xcode's organizer and a restore software image. However, the Dev Portal only offers 5.1 restore images for download. Are older ones available anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

There are links to the 5.0.1 firmware are as follows:

- iPhone 4S [here](http://appldnld.apple.com/iPhone4/041-3305.20111109.Bghy6/iPhone4,1_5.0.1_9A405_Restore.ipsw)
- iPhone 4 (GSM) [here](http://appldnld.apple.com/iPhone4/041-3309.20111109.64rtg/iPhone3,1_5.0.1_9A405_Restore.ipsw)
- iPhone 4 (CDMA) [here](http://appldnld.apple.com/iPhone4/041-3304.20111109.Vgtyh/iPhone3,3_5.0.1_9A405_Restore.ipsw)
- iPhone 3GS [here](http://appldnld.apple.com/iPhone4/041-3307.20111109.5tGhu/iPhone2,1_5.0.1_9A405_Restore.ipsw)
- iPad 2 WiFi [here](http://appldnld.apple.com/iPhone4/041-3310.20111109.Cfp76/iPad2,1_5.0.1_9A405_Restore.ipsw)
- iPad 2 GSM [here](http://appldnld.apple.com/iPhone4/041-3311.20111109.Vpr43/iPad2,2_5.0.1_9A405_Restore.ipsw)
- iPad 2 CDMA [here](http://appldnld.apple.com/iPhone4/041-3312.20111109.zp3ws/iPad2,3_5.0.1_9A405_Restore.ipsw)
- iPad [here](http://appldnld.apple.com/iPhone4/041-3308.20111109.Fvgtr/iPad1,1_5.0.1_9A405_Restore.ipsw)
- iPod touch 3G [here](http://appldnld.apple.com/iPhone4/041-3314.20111109.Mbgh6/iPod3,1_5.0.1_9A405_Restore.ipsw)
- iPod touch 4G [here](http://appldnld.apple.com/iPhone4/041-3313.20111109.Azxe3/iPod4,1_5.0.1_9A405_Restore.ipsw)

Could you use those at all?

Comment: [Macstories.net](http://macstories.net) has [linked to them when announcing iOS updates](http://www.macstories.net/news/apple-releases-ios-5/) (in case you want to download directly). Possibly there.

Comment: Started working, then popped up a message that "The device is not eligible for the requested build". The model is right, I've rechecked a few times...

Comment: Hmmm... I'm guessing Apple won't allow you to "back-install" even if you have the ipsw... Sorry, I can't think of anything else besides SSH blobs :(

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but if you haven't saved your SHSH blobs you can't restore an older version of iOS..
I recommend you to save your blobs with TinyUmbrella from now, so this doesn't happen again.