# iOS system symbol symbolication service

Tags: ios, crash-reports, symbolicate

I'm using [QuincyKit](http://quincykit.net/) to get crash logs from my iOS users. My Mac box serves as a back-end and symbolicates those crashes against the app debug symbols.

But in the vast majority of cases, it fails to symbolicate the stack entries that belong to the system libraries. Occasionally, this hampers the debugging. My Mac does not have the symbols for every thinkable version of iOS. [As discussed earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231779/force-download-ios-5-0-1-symbols), getting them without a device is not even officially supported.

Question - does anyone know of an online service which would symbolicate my crash logs against a good library of system symbols?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using QuincyKit, why not use [HockeyApp.net](http://HockeyApp.net) :) It is from the same developers, which is me and others :) HockeyApp has the system symbols of all available versions, so symbolication is not a problem at all.

The SDK is also advancing with a HockeyApp specific successor of the SDK: http://www.hockeyapp.net/blog/2012/8/13/hockeysdk-for-ios.html

Note: This new SDK symbolicates the system symbols right on the device where the crash happens in an async safe way as it should be.

Comment: I'm already paying for Web hosting - don't want to pay for another. If symbolication on device was available without the rest and for free, I'd jump right in.

Comment: Running something like HockeyApp costs money, someone has to pay for it. We have chosen to charge our customers, the developers. If you want free, the SDK is fully open source and is free. Take it and adjust it to your needs, like modifying it to use your own QuincyKit server and remove anything you don't need. Just don't remove the copyright :)

Comment: No, I understand and sympathize. It's just that you offer too much value. I'm not interested in Android, or analytics. Just in a slightly better version of QuincyKit :)